# display mysql query data as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How do i display mysql query result as an array

mydeptid is an array

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$DB->prefix("settings")." WHERE uid='$myuid'";
$result = $DB->query($sql);

while($row = $DB->fetchArray($result))
{
$uid=$row['uid'];
$mydeptid[]=$row['deptid'];


}

 $sql="SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPTID=$mydeptid ORDER BY DEPTNAME ASC";
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: use where IN  clause

Comment: it display only one result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per query, I understand, you have an array of department IDs. Hence, you will have to convert them into string before using them in a query. Check and try the below code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$DB->prefix("settings")." WHERE uid='$myuid'";
$result = $DB->query($sql);

while($row = $DB->fetchArray($result))
{
$uid=$row['uid'];
$mydeptid[]=$row['deptid'];
}

$allDeptIds = implode(",", $mydeptid);

$sql="SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPTID in ($allDeptIds) ORDER BY DEPTNAME ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single query with a JOIN

```
$sql = "SELECT D.* FROM ".$DB->prefix("settings")." T
JOIN DEPARTMENTS D  ON  D.DEPTID=T.deptid WHERE uid='$myuid'";
```